# How to stop S Voice from starting every time the headphones is inserted to Samsung Galaxy S5?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, headphones, s-voice

The moment I insert my headphones to my Samsung Galaxy S5 to play music, the S Voice will auto appear and my music stops. I have to cancel it and after a while, the S Voice repeats itself.

I've already deactivated the S Voice by double-tapping on the "home" key and unchecking “Open via the home key.”

How do I permanently stop the S Voice from auto appearing? Is there another way to stop S Voice from appearing whilst I play music over the headphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can depisable SVoice by going into

> settings > applications > SamsungVoice > disable